# How to get all images from a url to picturebox in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display all images in picturebox from url in c#. Say your suggestion via syntax.

Comment: Your question is not clear with the currently provided information. Describe what you exactly want and give an example.

Comment: If i give a url of localhost in picturebox that would retrieve all images from localhost folder.

Comment: So you mean that there are image files in a remote directory (in your case localhost) that should be displayed in there? How should they be displayed, a PictureBox is actually designed for one picture.

Comment: How can i display all images in c#? How to get all images from localhost directory by using URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create picture box at runtime on form load like this. And you have to only increament x and y value after every cycle

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 10, y = 10;
        string[] file = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\",             "*.jpg");
        PictureBox[] pb = new PictureBox[file.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
        {
            pb[i] = new PictureBox();
            pb[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100,100);
            pb[i].ImageLocation = file[i];
            pb[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
            this.Controls.Add(pb[i]);
            x += 100;
            if (i == 5)
            {
                 x = 10;
                 y += 120;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:-** Start by checking [PictureBox.Load(string URL) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx)

> Sets the ImageLocation to the specified URL and displays the image
>   indicated.

Comment: I need to display all images from specific URL.

Comment: @UmaShankar:- Try like this:- `yourPictureBox.ImageLocation = "url";`

Comment: @RahulTripathi According to his comment in the question, he wants to retrieve all images from a remote directory and display them in the PictureBox.

Comment: I have declared like that only. It access only a single image. I need to display multiple images by using Url

Comment: One URL only contains one image *or* probably points to an html file containing multiple URLs. So you'd need to extract these other URLs. And also have multiple PictureBox-elements to display multiple pictures.

Comment: Is there any possible to get images from localhost folder by using URL in c#?